# How to simplify this gamma function expression

Tags: gamma-function

In deriving the MLE estimate for the population proportion of a binomially distributed rv I need to simplify the following expression involving the gamma function for $l,m,a,b \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ \frac{\Gamma(l+m)}{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(l)}\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}$$

which can be found on page 71 of Bishops machine learning text.

As I simply don't know which gamma identities to use here, I was wondering how bishop simplified the expression to

$$\frac{\Gamma(m+a+l+b)}{\Gamma(m+a)\Gamma(l+b)}$$

Comment: It is not true in general (let $a \to 0$, the former $\to 0$ but not the latter) Maybe it meant for $l,m,a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: updated question

Comment: $\Gamma(n+1)= n!$ , $\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} = (a+b-1){a+b-2 \choose a-1}$